# check for persisted but not flushed user

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Lets say, I have a comment function that should always add a user to DB when the name still does not exist.

Currently I do a check first, and if not successfull I create a new Entity and persist the user.

```
    //try to find userName in DB
    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findByName($userName);

    //create new user if not existing
    if (!$user) {

        $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User();
        $user->setName($userName);
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    }
```

The `$user` entity will be added/linked to the `$comment` entity later. Then everything will be flushed.

My problem is now, that not only one comment is flushed, but normally multiple ones together. And there it appears, that a new user writes more than one comment.

Then my check in the repo wont work, because the new user is only persisted but not flushed yet. And I will get a unique failure, or the new username is added twice.

I know, I could create an array with the new persisted users and check this array just as I check the repo. But I would like to know if there are doctrine methods to handle this issue?

Comment: you could flush the new user after the persist

Comment: ah yes, I forgot to say that, I know its possible but I would like to do all in one connection/flush

Comment: What is relationship of entities? (bidirectional or unidirectional and where the owning/inverse sides)